# Coredata, cascade delete not working

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have a Coredata app with two entities with a to-many relation from A to B (Basic Teacher/Student, Author/Books, Department/Employee layout). I have set the deletion rules in the model relationship to cascade but it's not working. I can delete an item from A, but the related items from B still remain - thoughts? Per the Apple documentation, everything should work the way I have it setup.

Any thought/pointers would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those "duh" moments...

I was actually dealing with a group of 4 entities that were linked. I discovered in my add method, I forgot to add the relationship item in one of them - so two of the entities were not linked. Added the one line of code and all is good.

Comment: Thanks for having a "duh" moment, which helped me when I had one myself.